# Event to Observe for Mass Customer Group Updates?

Tags: magento, events

I'm using adminhtml_customer_save_after to catch the updates to customer's group, but it isn't hearing about any updates made via massaction drop down on the main customer grid screen, and I can't find an event that does listen to that. Any tips on finding the correct event to observe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since massAssignGroupAction is associated with mass customers group update,  this event adminhtml_customer_save_after is not dispatched, I am afraid there is no other event associated with that action, you might want to rewrite this model `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer and override _afterSave` method to achieve the desired results.